# What can cause a ErrImagePull in kubernetes? The registry returns 403

Tags: kubernetes

Hey I'm trying to get a pipeline to work with kubernetes but I keep getting `ErrImagePull`

Earlier I was getting something along the lines `authentication failed`.
I created a secret in the namespace of the pod and referring to it in the deployment file:

```
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: "registry-secret"
```

I still get `ErrImagePull` but now for different reasons. When describing the failed pod I get:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m46s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned <project> to <server>
  Normal   Pulling    3m12s (x4 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Pulling image "<container_url>"
  Warning  Failed     3m12s (x4 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "<container_url>": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Requesting bear token: invalid status code from registry 403 (Forbidden)
  Warning  Failed     3m12s (x4 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     3m (x6 over 4m45s)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    2m46s (x7 over 4m45s)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "<container_url>"
```

I guess the Registry is returning 403, but why? Does it mean the user in `registry-secret` is not allowed to pull the image?

Comment: what's the type of secret you created?

Comment: Which pipeline? How did you create it? Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I had the third jab and was in bed since.
But I found the error. So I had a typo and my secret was in fact not created in the correct namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has posted in the comment that the problem is resolved:

> I found the error. So I had a typo and my secret was in fact not created in the correct namespace.